# Drift velocity - it should be increasing more and more

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, conductors

The drift velocity formula is $\mu_rE$. We know that it's constant throughout the wire since we know current is constant.

I wonder how this is true logically. The thing is the more electron approaches the positive terminal, the attraction force is bigger there (due to less distance), hence $E$ is bigger since $F=qe$. If so, the more close electron gets to positive terminal, its drift velocity should be increasing due to the formula. Why is that not happening logically?

If you say that they get deaccelerated as well, that's true, but then deacceleration should be happening by bigger amount closer to positive terminal than more far away from it. And I'm not sure why that is then.

Looking for logical, intuitive explanation.

Comment: The field (V/cm) remains constant if the resistivity is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The thing is the more electron approaches the positive terminal, the attraction force is bigger there (due to less distance), hence E is bigger since F=qe.

This is the mistake. The $E$ is roughly uniform so $F$ is also roughly uniform.

You are thinking of the E field from a dipole as you approach one of the poles. This would be a reasonable approximation of the field in the absence of the conductor. However with the conductor there are surface charges induced. These surface charges disturb the dipole field outside the conductor somewhat, but they have a huge effect on the field inside the conductor. They make the E field inside the wire be approximately constant in magnitude and parallel to the axis of the wire.

Comment: what do you mean by surface charges ? i know inside wire, we got atoms that have mobile electrons so electron while accelerating to the positive terminal, they still experiences the electric field attraction by the neighobing atoms' electric fields, so the motion is like move forward by 2m, move back by 1m.  Is this what you mean ? but probably not.

Comment: Maybe you mean a different thing: analogy would be 2 plates (positive and negative) and inside , E is uniform. Maybe if I understand this, i can understand the current asked question. But since you mentioned E is constant due to surface charges, plate analogy might not help as there is no wire

Comment: @Chemistry surface charges are the charges that reside on the surface of a conductor. Here is the Wikipedia link https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_charge and here is the famous paper by Jackson on the topic https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996AmJPh..64..855J/abstract and here is my favorite paper on the topic https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/index.php?eID=dumpFile&t=f&f=138440&token=2cc8a71e4fdbf159121c6b8ef8348952a2e0c197

Comment: Thanks for the links. reading on them ! so without battery(if we only have copper wire), in that wire alone, we wouldn't have surface charges right ? the charges of copper only get arranged to the surface when wire is connected to the battery  even when circuit is open, right ?

Comment: @Chemistry you will get surface charges induced on a conductor in any E field. But they are only arranged to produce current when they are attached to a battery or other source

Comment: Without battery, wire still has free electrons that move back and forth within small area so they dont have net movement overally. But as I said, without battery, would you still have surface charges ? You mentioned “in any E field”. I guess you meant external E field and not the E fields of charges of wire itself. In this case, without battery, we wont have surface charges in the wire. All correct ?

Answer (score 2):

In a vacuum you are right, the velocity of your charge carrier would increase indefinitely.

However, in practice electrons lose energy to the medium through phonon scattering or crystal defects. This leads to a finite "terminal" velocity (called saturation velocity) for a given material.

An analogy could be that of a skydiver who reaches a finite speed quite quickly because of air resistance. If there were no air resistance the skydiver would accelerate indefinitely similarly to your charge carrier in a vacuum.

Comment: Nice analogy, the skydiver.